# Translating equation into python

Tags: python

[image]

I am trying to compute this equation in python but I'm having problem understanding the loop and I am kinda confused at the summation of the summation.

This is how far i got and I have trouble implementing the summation of the summation. Any idea?

```
import numpy as np
stdev =np.zeros(N)
m_sum=np.zeros([lam,N])

for i in xrange(N):
    for k in xrange(lam):
        m_sum[k,i]+=(1/(lam))*m[k,i]
    stdev[i]=1/(lam-1)*(m[k,i]-m_sum[k,i])**2
```

Comment: is your formula correct? I think the left square bracket should be on the left of the left Σ

Comment: I think you are right , I think it doesn't make sense to take the square root of the square .

Comment: and also is one of the (k=1) actually (i-1) instead?

if you want to do summation, i heavily recommend sympy to do it. you can pretty print out your equation to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's confusing because the same index variable `k` is being used for both inner and outer loop, so it's ambiguous.  However, since this is the standard formula for standard deviation, we know from context what the intention is:

```
import math
import numpy as np
stdev = np.zeros(N)
means = np.zeros(N)

for i in xrange(N):
    m = 0
    for k in xrange(lam):
        m += m[k,i]
    means[i] = m/lam

    v = 0
    for k in xrange(lam):
        v += (m[k,i] - means[i])**2
    stdev[i] = math.sqrt(v)/(lam-1)
```

Note that `numpy` also has functions to directly calculate standard deviations of columns of your matrix `m`, but if you're just doing this as an exercise of directly translating a math equation into code, then this is how you would do it.

Comment: Thanks Amit ! You're right , I was so engrossed in the summation I forgot to basics :) it's a std! Thanks :)

Comment: Also, since Python 3.4 there's [`statistics.stdev()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev) in the standard library.